# Android wrap text of an editText which is aligned just right of an textView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Wanted a fill in the blanks type layout e.g.

My name is _______ . I work at ________ . 
like [image]

Such that if a user enters some long text inside blanks it should wrap the text inside the editText like :
My name is *Akshat Tailang Bhatt* . I work at *abcdefghijklmnop qrstuvwxyzabcdefghi(words should be wrapped)* .

Issue is the whole editText wraps to next line instead of some new words in it: 
[image]

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: You want that edit text width will be increased as per words length??

Comment: Try giving fix width with single line true

Comment: @Bunny First i simply used relative layout with textView and editText relative to each other which obviously failed , then i tried a library by google flexbox which also didn't resolve the issue. Attaching screenshots in the question.

Comment: @shahid17june i have just added screen shot i want the editText not take the whole next line space but wrap as a normal paragraph.

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan Can you please elaborate after seeing screenshots in the question, i am unable to understand how giving single line attribute will solve the issue because i still want it to be multiple lines.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this by combining standard `TextView`s with standard `EditText`s. My best idea is to use a single `TextView` with two `ClickableSpan`s in order to open the keyboard, but I'm not sure how to do live updating while the user types.